# Error using orderBy and startAfterDocument in a query

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

When using orderBy and startAfterDocument in the same query, I get the following error:

> failed: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.goog...

This error is being caught when I try to receive the next set of documents.
Tried to create an index using the link provided in the error but it's a single index using the 'finalTimeStamp' field is being generated and firestore throws out the following exception.

```
this index is not necessary, configure using single field index controls
```

In my single field indexes, the descending index for a collection scope is already enabled.

My code:

```dart
    if (_lastVisible == null) {
      try {
        data = await chatList
            .document(widget.currentUserId)
            .collection('inbox')
            .orderBy('finalTimeStamp', descending: true)
            .limit(10)
            .getDocuments();
      } catch (e) {
        print('caught error 1');
      }
    } else {
      try {
        data = await chatList
            .document(widget.currentUserId)
            .collection('inbox')
            .orderBy('finalTimeStamp', descending: true)
            .startAfterDocument(_lastVisible)
            .limit(10)
            .getDocuments();
      } catch (e) {
        print('caught error 2');
      }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you set `_lastVisible`?

Comment: I've set it after this if else condition. If data.documents.length > 0, I set _lastVisible to the last document.

Comment: I've run into the same issue. I've narrowed it down in a way that it seems to only fail when the paginated query is with descending order on the subcollection. Have you tried with `ascending: true`? Ascending by any field works for me surprisingly. Anyway, I've opened a ticket with their support team, since it appears to be a bug on the SDK potentially

Comment: I'm sorry for not posting this earlier but it is a limitation in firebase querying. startAfter can only be performed on the index on which you have set the orderBy query.

Comment: @rajeshchaganti so using startAfter(_lastVisible.field) instead of startAfterDocument() resolves the issue?

Comment: @atereshkov Sure, it'll work properly if all your field values you are performing the startAfter() on are unique. I solved my issue by creating a reference field in the documents which references to the same document. While querying I've set an orderBy(Ref) condition and startAfterDocument or startAfter(_lastVisible.ref) conditions work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The orderBy and startAfter or startAfterDocuments should be performed on the same field.

In my question above I've performed orderBy on the finalTimeStamp field and was using startAfterDocument which considers the document ID while ordering the documents. Hence, firestore throws an error.

You can solve this issue in 2 ways:

1. You can perform startAfter() on finalTimeStamp field. (Didn't consider this for my case because I though there may be multiple documents with the same finalTimeStamp. Using this could give out wrong results)
2. I created a chatRef field in my documents referencing the same document. I then created an index in firestore to order my documents by finalTimeStamp first and chatRef later. Now while querying, I performed orderBy() twice on finalTimeStamp and chatRef along with the startAfterDocument().